# Angular - set value for select with ngRepeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, select

I'm trying to achieve a dropdown box with months of the year as options. I don't want to manually create an array with the month names in, so I've done it like this:

```
<select ng-model="selected.month">
  <option ng-repeat="month in repeatX(12) track by $index" value="{{$index}}">{{newDate(2015,$index,1) | date: 'MMMM'}}</option>
</select>
```

Then in my controller:

```
$scope.repeatX = function(num){ return new Array(num); }
$scope.newDate = function(y,m,d){ return new Date(y,m,d); }
```

So the `ngRepeat` works off an array with 12 empty fields in. It then uses the index of the repeat and the date filter. The drop down displays properly, for example the first option is 'January' with the value '0'.

I can't seem to set the initial value. For example I try this in my controller:

```
$scope.selected = { month: '8' };
```

And I've tried it as an integer:

```
$scope.selected = { month: 8 };
```

Neither set the drop down to September. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: angular version you are using?

Comment: @K.Toress version 1.4

Comment: it working here http://plnkr.co/edit/sXzd1wNwu26VDJAfjJsT?p=preview version is `1.4.6`

Comment: Silly me, I was using version 1.3 not 1.4. As soon as I upgraded to 1.4 it worked

Comment: glad :), i think if you can come up with a reusable directive to populate this select box, then it will be good because in this case `$scope.newDate` function will call 24 times at the first and when there is change happen again 12 times run, this will happen all the scope changes. so if you can populate the data first and generate the select after that then it will be more suitable.

Comment: Yes I see what you mean. Thanks for the advice

Comment: here is a demo :) http://plnkr.co/edit/DNMY3CCa1DEiJm0J3VIR?p=preview

Comment: Ah yeh that's pretty cool! Cheers